# How to pass the zero-filled multidimensional array to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, visual-c++

I want to pass my zero-filled nullMat multidimensional pointer array to a function called setGraphics in the constructor. In whatever way I try to do so I get "argument incompatible" or something in the lines of that.

The cpp file Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>

Test::Test(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{  
    ui.setupUi(this);
    lifeMatrix(5);
    setGraphics(nullMat(), 50);
    
}

void Test::setGraphics(bool **lifeMat, int scale)
{
    QGraphicsScene* scena = new QGraphicsScene();
    ui.view->setScene(scena);
    int lDydis = 50;        // nusistato langelio dydis, bus galima pakeist i variable
    for (int row = 0; row < scale; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < scale; column++)
        {
            QGraphicsRectItem* rect = new QGraphicsRectItem();
            rect->setRect(row * lDydis, column * lDydis, lDydis, lDydis);          
            if (lifeMat[row][column] == 1) rect->setBrush(Qt::white);
            if (lifeMat[row][column] == 0) rect->setBrush(Qt::black);
            rect->show();
            scena->addItem(rect);

        }
    }
}
```

and the header file Test.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_Test.h"

class Test : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Test(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    void nullMat(bool **lifeMat) { for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) lifeMat[i][j] = 0; };
    void setGraphics(bool** lifeMat, int);
    int scale; // common, nustato matricos dydi rpagal column/row nariu skaiciu
    void lifeMatrix(int scale)
    {
        // Matricos dydis x*y
        bool** lifeMat = new bool* [scale];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < scale; ++i) lifeMat[i] = new bool[scale];
    }
private:
    Ui::TestClass ui;
    
};
```

I don't know how to solve this one and I have been trying for quite some time.
Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: You are using `nullMat()` as if it were returning something (`setGraphics(nullMat(), 50);`), but it is defined as void: `void nullMat(bool **lifeMat)`, taking an argument. How do you want to have it?

Comment: Use [C++ containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and enable all warnings and debug info when compiling (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you would use `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems clear you don't understand when to return values from functions. `lifeMatrix` is creating the matrix so it need to return the matrix. `nullMat` is just modifying the matrix, so it doesn't need to return the matrix.

Rewrite your code like this

```
class Test : public QMainWindow
{
    ...
    void nullMat(bool **lifeMat) { ... }
    ...
    bool **lifeMatrix(int scale)
    {
        // Matricos dydis x*y
        bool** lifeMat = new bool* [scale];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < scale; ++i) lifeMat[i] = new bool[scale];
        return lifeMat;
    }
    ...
}

Test::Test(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{  
    ui.setupUi(this);
    bool** mat = lifeMatrix(5);
    nullMat(mat);
    setGraphics(mat, 50);
}
```

The code still seems to be leaking memory as the matrix is never deleted anywhere. Maybe you actually need to make the matrix a member variable. That would change the code around again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! And yes, I'm still deep in the learning part of coding and your help really made me understand my mistake. This did help me eradicate this problem but now I am getting an exception `Exception thrown at 0x00007FF701DA2B88 in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. occurred` in this line `if (lifeMat[row][collumn] == 1) rect->setBrush(Qt::white);`

Comment: So I think the problem is here `lifeMatrix(5); ... setGraphics(nullMat(), 50);`. Should the value of `scale` be 5 or 50? At the moment `lifeMatrix` is creating a 5x5 matrix, but `setGraphics` is using a 50x50 matrix.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It should be 5 in both cases, I messed up while writing. I am new to this community and you already made my day. Thanks!